# windows phone sidebar menu

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have some application on my Android. an some of this apps have unvisible menu on left side. when user clicks on icon on the top of form it shows menu on left but do not close current form. here is picture from GooGLE+ app for android.

I want to create app with left side menu as in Google+ app but for Windows Phone 7.X

I have Visual Studio 2010, Silverlight 4 and Silverlight 5 installed. And i use C# as a language

[image: Google+ menu on the left side]

Update(clarification): My question is what is the alternative to the menu in the picture in WP platform?

Comment: Well, good luck!  And the question is?

Comment: It's generally considered bad form to design against the conventions of a platform, e.g., using an Android UI on a WP app. However, have a look at the Popup control in the Coding 4 Fun toolkit.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I am trying to find its alternative in WP platform.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is not an easy way to do that like iOS. But you can use Visual State Manager.

Basically, Shape a bigger screen than your stage. Then, you need to create a state which will shift your screen a little bit left in the stage and you can use a button. You need to call the state on button's on click method.

PS: Do not use storyboard. Use the States it is easiest way to do that.